# Jquery hover state dependent on class name

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

It's a little difficult to explain, but what I am trying to achieve is to apply a class / css to a group of divs with the same class name. Specifically it will be a gallery displaying thumbnails. They all appear together but are grouped by class name. When you hover on an image for a specific class, all images with the same class will remain opaque, while the rest change their opacity. Perhaps this could be achieved by changing the display of an overlay div?

So essentially I need some way of displaying div's with the same class in the same way, irrespective of their class name on hover.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

For example (when hovering on either of class 1 they are opaque, class 2 are transparent & vice versa):

```
<div class="thumbnail 1">
<img>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail 1">
<img>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail 2">
<img>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail 2">
<img>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with the same class in the same way, irrespective of their class name on hover."  Do they have the same class or not?

Comment: There will be sets of images grouped by a class, but because these will be generated dynamically, I won't know what the class is. Therefore is there a way to just select items of the same class, without knowing what it is? I have found a site which does something similar to what I want: sam-robinson.com/stills

Comment: Yes, let me update my answer to make that clear to you.

Comment: @Tim, can you update your question with an excerpt of your HTML markup, and add an concrete example using actual class names from that markup? As it stands, what you mean by `specific class`, `all images with the same class` and `without knowing what it is` is quite vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using jQuery. This code will work for any group of elements and classes; you don't need to know what the classes will be in advance. It simply finds all the elements that don't have the class of the one you're hovering over and dims them.

If this is your HTML:

```
<span class="a">a</span>
<span class="a">b</span>
<span class="a">c</span>
<span class="b">d</span>
<span class="b">e</span>
<span class="b">f</span>
```

..then, this jQuery should work fine.

```
$('span').hover(function() {
    var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('span:not(.' + theClass + ')').animate({'opacity': 0.2}, 300);
}, function() {
    $('span').animate({'opacity': 1}, 300); //restore all spans to 100% opacity
});
```

[Live jsFiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/S7xKn/1/)

Comment: Thanks that brilliant! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your classes are generated dynamically, you'll first want to get the class of the current element and then if you want to do something to elements that do not belong to a class:

```
$('div').hover(function () {
  // Get the class
  var selector = $(this).attr('class');
  $('div:not(' + selector + ')').each( function () {
    //...
  });
});
```

From there you can use jQuery's animate function to have them change their opacity.

For more information on the not-selector, visit the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) website.

Comment: They do belong to a class, but I won't be able to specify what it is because it is generated dynamically. I have found a site which does something similar to what I want: http://sam-robinson.com/stills

Comment: Thanks also for your input, this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy to do. Without writing the whole function for you, the selectors are simple:

```
$('div.hoverclass').hover(function() { 
  // any other logic you need to sort out
  $('img.imageclass').not('.hoverclass').doOpacityStuff();
});
```

Where "hoverclass" is the class shared by the group of divs with their respective images, "imageclass" is a class that all images with this hovering functionality share (so that you don't affect your other icons and unrelated images), and "doOpacityStuff()" is the point at which you can chain in your other opacity functions.